# Как в WP плагине поменять текст\ссылку?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть WP сайт: https://transscreen.ru/

Поставил плагин UltimatelySocial. Он в подвале отображает: powered by UltimatelySocial в виде гиперссылки.

Я скрыл текст добавив в style.css моей темы:

```
.sfsiplus_footerLnk{
display: none;
}
```

Но в коде страницы оно осталось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас хочу полностью удалить или заменить текст\линк в этом диве.

Подскажите в каком бы это файле это прописано или как сделать чтоб вообще не отображалось в коде страницы?

Comment: сам разобрался. использовал totalcommander и поиск текста внутри файлов в папке плагина. так и нашел файл.

Comment: При обновлении плагина, Ваши изменения затрутся) Чего точно не нужно делать, так это менять его исходный код)